# Netbean Service with Sql Server 2008

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, netbeans, jdbc

I have been trying to connect netbean service for database explorer with **Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Driver 3.0** but unsuccessful always.The zipped jdbc driver has two jars I tested it with **sqljdbc** but it says that is is not compatible with java 1.7 so I tried it with **sqljdbc4** and now it shows following error:
[image]

I have enable **TCP/IP connection** to the server.
What is the right way to connect netbean service with **sql server 2008**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution to this problem actuall you should use the port **57634** for TCP/IP connections. Well you can change the port if you want by going to :
**Configuration Manager -> Protocols for SQL SQLEXPRESS > Properties of TCP/IP.** In the IP Addresses  tab, set the **TCPPort in section IPAll to 1433**.